# What is the best way to gain size in ankle area

Tags: exercise

How can I increase ankle mass?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The ankle is mostly comprised of bone and tendons.  There's no way to make it bigger unless you got so fat that your body stored fat at the foot and ankle.